# On localization and integral domains

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

I'm attempting to solve exercise 5 from chapter 3 in Atiyah-McDonald's text on commutative algebra; in particular, it asks if 'being an integral domain' is a local property. The counter-example I found is the following, and was interested in asking whether it made any sense.

Consider the ring $A=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(xy)$; evidently, $A$ is not an integral domain, as it is a quotient of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ by an ideal which is not prime. Because prime ideals in $A$ are such that their contraction in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is a prime ideal that contains $(xy)$, the only possible prime ideals in $A$ are $p=(x)/(xy)$ and $q=(y)/(xy)$; one can verify directly that these are both in fact prime.

My intuition behind this exercise is that $A_p$ *should* be an integral domain, because the expression $\frac{x+(xy)}{1}\cdot\frac{y+(xy)}{1}=0$ fails to be a product of two non zero elements in $A_p$, seeing as $\frac{x+(xy)}{1}=0$ in the localization, becuase $y+(xy)\in (A-p)$ and $(x+(xy))(y+(xy))=0$.

I'm not quite sure if this observation is enough to assert that $A_p$ (and hence, by symmetry, $A_q$ as well) is an integral domain. I would greately appreciate any advice or suggestion which may help, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd try $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition that $A_p$ and $A_q$ are domains is correct - a little more pushing will show that $A_p\cong k[x]_{(x)}$. Unfortunately, your claim that $p$ and $q$ are the only primes is false: $(x,y)$ is a prime ideal in $A$ which is not of the form you claim (there are many more).

Comment: And to end the OP's hopes: $A_{(x,y)}$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: Aaah that's right... I didn't check my reasoning through properly then. If I may ask, how would one go about finding all prime ideals in A then?

Comment: Well, usually one does not answer that question so explicitly: it's like asking for all the numbers in some subset of the reals. In this case, we can actually write down all the ideals: they're $(x)$, $(y)$, $(m(x),y)$, and $(x,m(y))$ as $m$ ranges over irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb Q[x]$. What's going on here is that $A/(x)\cong \Bbb Q[y]$, and we know all the irreducibles of $\Bbb Q[y]$. (Really, geometrically, $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is two copies of $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb Q}$ intersecting at the origin, and that's what I'm thinking about.)

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you very much for the help; I especially appreciated the geometric insight :)